# Bootstrap Menu navbar will not open on iPhone, but works in Chrome mobile simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The stacked menu button will not open on iPhone, but it does work in Chrome iPhone simulator view. It's as if a recent update to iOS has broken it. I could have sworn it was working before, less than a month or two ago. The app is located at https://mybestbody.herokuapp.com. I tried reloading several times. I wish I could view the JavaScript console on iPhone. Here is the menu:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Best Body</a>
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="<%=@homeActive%>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="<%=@aboutActive%>"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li class="<%=@contactActive%>"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to 'My Profile', user_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Register', new_user_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### Chrome

[image: chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tracked down the problem and changed the `<a>` line to

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```